# How to restrict characters during keypress event in h:inputText

Tags: javascript, jsf

I need an input component to accept only numbers as in `[0-9]`. I have achieved this by server side conversion/validation:

```
<h:inputText ... converter="javax.faces.Integer" />
```

However, it still allows other characters while entering in the UI. How can I prevent that during the `keypress` event?

```
<h:inputText ... converter="javax.faces.Integer" onkeypress="...help?" />
```

Comment: This is not exactly a JSF problem, but just JavaScript. In that case, this question is a dupe: [Best way to restrict a text field to numbers only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764821/best-way-to-restrict-a-text-field-to-numbers-only)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h:inputText id="presentReading" styleClass="labelfont" label="Present Reading"    converter="javax.faces.Integer"value="#{FuelFilling1.presentReading}" maxlength="10">
   <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="10"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Alternatively, you can use JQuery or Javascript to validate on the client-side on keypress. Are you okay to use Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend sticking with jsf validation.

```
<f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" type="number" />
```

You can use ajax in order to validate in real time if you don't want to have to submit the form to the get response.  Doing keypress validation with javascript/jQuery can be done, but is a pain unless you have a really good reason to do it that way.