# Javascript character restriction and calling a function with getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a JS function that checks and restricts certain characters typed in input forms.
The code look like this:

```
var alphaOnly = /[sA-Za-z\söÖäÄüÜ]/g;
var alphaextraOnly = /[A-Za-z\-&/'"\öÖäÄüÜ]/g;
var alphadigitsOnly = /[sA-Za-z\söÖäÄüÜ\s1234567890]/g;
var digitsOnly = /[1234567890]/g;
var integerOnly = /[0-9\.]/g;
var mailOnly = /[a-z\.@]/g;

function restrictCharacters(myfield, e, restrictionType) {
  if (!e) var e = window.event
  if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
  else if (e.which) code = e.which;
  var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
  // if they pressed esc... remove focus from field...
  if (code==27) { this.blur(); return false; }
  // ignore if they are press other keys
  // strange because code: 39 is the down key AND ' key...
  // and DEL also equals .
  if (!e.ctrlKey && code!=9 && code!=8 && code!=36 && code!=37 && code!=38 && (code!=39 || (code==39 && character=="'")) && code!=40) {
    if (character.match(restrictionType)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }   
}
```

It works when I add `onkeypress` to input like this:

```
<input type="text" class="span4 register_input" id="firma" name="firma" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(this, event, alphaOnly);" />
```

But I want to do that with `getElementById` in the script. I tried to add this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("firma").onkeypress = restrictCharacters(this, event, alphaOnly);
}
```

But it didn't work... Help please.

Comment: possible solution in jsfiddle? :)

Comment: You should `e.which` in preference to `e.keyCode`. That way you avoid having to deal with non-printable keypresses. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3765349/96100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass the arguments like that to onkeypress you would need to use a wrapper function

```
document.getElementById("firma").onkeypress = function (e)
    {
        return restrictCharacters(this,e,alphaOnly);
    };
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BjU2e/5/

Comment: also, I don't know where exactly shoud I put this

Comment: this was a replacement for your current document.getElementById line

Comment: could you edit this jsfiddle update/save it so it work than link me back please? http://jsfiddle.net/BjU2e/4/

Comment: Updated http://jsfiddle.net/BjU2e/5/ I removed the null check as you have it in your routine

Comment: just noticed kobigurk got there before me glad its working now :)

Comment: please cut me some time, what excatly did you change in script? It seems that now is working better :)

Comment: All that changed was I updated the second box id to firma2, then appended the script I wrote above to the end.  The reason you need to do it this way is when placing code inside the onkeypress in html it is essentially wrapping it in a function like in the code above but you don't see that function.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to onkeypress the result of `restrictCharacters(this,event,alphaOnly)` instead of a function delegate. A correct version is in the following jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xL47r/1/

For future reference :

```
document.getElementById("firma2").onkeypress = function(e) {
    return restrictCharacters(this,e,alphaOnly); 
};
```

Comment: also, question like on Engineer's answer

Comment: edited - it's instead of the second code block you posted. Also, I added a fix.

Comment: could you edit this jsfiddle update/save it so it work than link me back please? http://jsfiddle.net/BjU2e/4/

Comment: there you go. Notice that in the original fiddle, you had two divs with id "firma". I change the password one to "firma2".

Comment: yea i forgot to change the id of second input of firma... sorry for thath...7

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("firma").onkeypress = function(){
     return restrictCharacters.call(this/*becauseof 'this.blur()' */, this,event,alphaOnly);
};
```

Comment: after what should I insert this in my code? beacause if i put it after last } it doesn't work

Comment: @dzordz It's straightforward. You should replace your `document.getElem...` line (within `window.onload` callback) with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `this` from `e.target`

```
document.getElementById("firma").onkeypress = function(e) {
     restrictCharacters(e.target,e,alphaOnly);
}
```

Comment: could you edit this jsfiddle update/save it so it work than link me back please? http://jsfiddle.net/BjU2e/4/

Answer (score 0):

> You have wrong syntex to bind event with dom .here it is : `window.onload = function () {
>           var ab = document.getElementById("firma");
>           ab.setAttribute("onkeypress", "restrictCharacters(this,event, true)");
>       }`

Comment: could you edit this jsfiddle update/save it so it work than link me back please? http://jsfiddle.net/BjU2e/4/