# Validation for digits only using jQuery validator not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using jQuery Validator for validations. However for number or digits only the validation not working.

It is accepting special characters also. Instead of letters and special characters I want only digits.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("Length", function(value, element) {
  // var password_regex = this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$/.test(value);
  if ($(element).val() != '' && $(element).val().length !== 20) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}, "Please enter exact 20 digit.");

$("#add_form_id").validate({
  rules: {
    rational_id: {
      // number: true,
      Length: true,
      maxlength: 30,
      digits: true,

    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you add the markup for your `#add_form_id`?

Comment: its working on form submit

Comment: So you actually want to prevent people from even typing a non number into the field prior to submitting the form? If so, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764821/best-way-to-restrict-a-text-field-to-numbers-only).

Comment: use this validation plugin https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.jsv

Comment: Stll not working .I am able to add letter and special characters

Comment: Why it's not working ? Any errors?

Comment: No error occur . Still it taking letters and special characters too.I only want numbers.

Comment: The validation check only happens when the form is submitted. If you want to prevent people even typing non numeric characters you will need to use something like `keydown` events in conjunction with your validation.