# How Do I Make A textbox Not Take in < or >

Tags: html, textbox

How Do I Make A textbox Not Take in < or >?
I Have A project that uses html to display text but using html tags can mess up my site so I need help making my html textbox not take in < or >.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3764821/62576

Comment: There is no way to leave out just 1 symbol

Comment: Yes, there is, and you're wanting to leave out two *symbols*. Read those answers again. There are many of them.

Comment: I see at least 15 different answers to the question I linked that could easily be modified to do what you're asking. Apparently, you didn't read enough of them.

Comment: I tried alot of them and I don't have jquery so most of them don't work i tried messageInput.value.replace(">", "") but it did not work

Comment: There are many answers that are plain Javascript that don't need jquery. Do you know any Javascript at all?

Comment: I do know javascript and when i do any of them it takes the < and the > away but if i do <button></button> or other tags the tags still show up so I am looking to make it so you can not type the < or the > in the textbox